# Send mail from jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery UI dialog box where I am having 4 text field which are sender email, receiver email, Title and the message.

I am getting the title and message from somewhere else and I am storing it in the text field of the dialog box.
This is my code -

```
   var $dialog = $('<div id="myDialog"></div>')
              .html('<form>Sender Email <input id=senderemailAddresss type="text" class="w3-input w3-border" value="abc@example.com" size="25"><br> Receiver Email <input id=receiveremailAddresss class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" value="bcd@example.com" size="25"><br>Title<input id=title class="w3-input w3-border" type="text"> <br>Messgae <textarea id=message class="w3-input w3-border"  style="height:60px type="text" rows="4" cols="20"></form>')
               .dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true,
                   height: 700,
                   width: 500,
                   draggable: false,
                   title: "Send Mail",
                   buttons: { 
                        "Send": 
                        function() 
                        { $(this).dialog("close"); }, 
                        "Cancel": 
                        function() 
                        { $(this).dialog("close"); }

                        }, 
                   open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                     //  $("#title").val($rootScope.maintitle);
                    $(this).find('#title').val("Title is :"+ title);
                    $(this).find(text).val("Message is :"+test1+" \n "+"\n new line :"+ test2+"\n again new line " +test3)

                   $(this).css('overflow', 'auto');
                   }
                  });
                 $("#title").val('');
                 $dialog.dialog('open');
```

Now, here when clicking on send I am closing the the dialog box instead I want to send the mail. How could I do this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclaimer - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 0):

The only way is going to bring up the email interface but it won't necessarily send the email. They would have to do that themselves.

```
window.open('mailto:john@smith.com');
```

or

```
<a href='mailto:john@smith.com'>Click Me</a>
```

Reference:

http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send the email directly from jquery (front-end) straight. It has to be done on server side. You can send by ajax your modal content to a server then the server send the email. For example sending email in php :
In php :https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Otherwise, you can take @trevster344 advice and use "mailto":
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send the email from UI. But you can use third party service like mailgun.com. Or write backend code as mentioned above.